# JPA, Spring Webservice Select with NOT IN and IN

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql, notin

I'm trying to do this select:

```
SELECT c FROM Incident c 
WHERE c.incidentID IN 
  ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE tagName IN ( d.tagName=?1 ) 
   AND d.incidentID NOT IN 
   (SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE tagName IN (a.tagName=?2))    
  )
```

In my system with JPA/Spring I'm getting the error:

```
"HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:"
```

Is something that I'm doing wrong in the syntax?
I tested it on my Database(HANA) and it worked alright.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit More Errors Log**

My latest try was:

```
SELECT c FROM Incident c WHERE c.incidentID IN 
( SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE d.tagName IN 
( d.tagName=?1 ) AND d.incidentID NOT IN 
( SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE a.tagName IN (a.tagName=?2) ))
```

**Edit**

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c FROM Incident c WHERE c.incidentID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE d.tagName IN ( d.tagName=?1 ) AND d.incidentID NOT IN ( SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE a.tagName IN (a.tagName=?2) ))].  [117, 131] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression. [215, 229] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c FROM Incident c WHERE c.incidentID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE d.tagName IN ( d.tagName=?1 ) AND d.incidentID NOT IN ( SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE a.tagName IN (a.tagName=?2) ))].  [117, 131] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression. [215, 229] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression.] with root cause Local Exception Stack:  Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c FROM Incident c WHERE c.incidentID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE d.tagName IN ( d.tagName=?1 ) AND d.incidentID NOT IN ( SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE a.tagName IN (a.tagName=?2) ))].  [117, 131] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression. [215, 229] 
The expression at index {0} is not a valid expression.
```

**Latest Try:**

```
List<String> list_add_tags = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list_remove_tags = new ArrayList<String>();

// creating custom sql_query
String sql_query = "SELECT c FROM Incident c WHERE c.incidentID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(d.incidentID) FROM TagIncident d WHERE d.tagName IN ( :add_tags ) AND d.incidentID NOT IN ( SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE a.tagName IN (:remove_tags)))";

TypedQuery<Incident> query = em.createQuery(sql_query, Incident.class);

query.setParameter("add_tags", list_add_tags);
query.setParameter("remove_tags", list_remove_tags);

return query.getResultList();
```

Still doesn't work. =(

ERROR:

```
You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter add_tags with expected type of class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using? Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA or one of the lesser-known DataNucleaus, Toplink, ObjectDB? In Hibernate you can assign lists, as is shown in the examples in section 4.6.17.5 the JPA specifications, but in their own words they thought they supported it as a bonus feature. Maybe you should try removing the parentheses around the parameter? The official example does imply you shouldn't need them.

Comment: EclipseLink 2.6.0, removed the parenthesis from the IN with the lists and it worked, what could I understand by doing that? How do I check my JPA version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I only use native queries, because I can test them easier, but try this:

```
SELECT c FROM Incident c 
WHERE c.incidentID IN 
  ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE tagName IN :at 
   AND d.incidentID NOT IN 
   (SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE tagName IN :rt )    
  )
```

This should work with `query.setParameter("tag", theListOfTags)`. Just be aware that versions of Hibernate before 5.0.7 have a syntax problem with parameters in parentheses.

An empty list will also generate a syntax error.

JPA specifications show this as valid syntax in their examples, so any JPA provider *should* support it:

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN :empTypes
```

Comment: The tags are different, the tag is something I don't want in the last Select and it is some tag that I want in the second Select. I will try without parenthesis.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have to be called `tag`. That's just using named parameters, so you don't have to use positional and call `setParameter` twice, or keep track of positions in complex queries with lots of parameters. The biggest correction I made was removing `[ad].tagName=?1` from there, because you are making the comparison with the `IN (list of values)` part.

Comment: You are right! It's a list! I will try that, thanks!

Comment: If i just add it as:

`SELECT c FROM Incident c 
WHERE c.incidentID IN 
  ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT d.incidentID FROM TagIncident d WHERE tagName IN ( tag1,tag2,tag3 ) 
   AND d.incidentID NOT IN 
   (SELECT a.incidentID FROM TagIncident a WHERE tagName IN (  tag4,tag5,tag6 ))    
  )`

It should work didn't?

Comment: Updated my latest try, pls check if you can!

Comment: I removed the parenthesis and inserted as you said and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot mate! I guess my version EclipseLink 2.6.0 does not support parenthesis in NOT IN or IN besides when there is a select inside.

You saved my day! =D

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `JPA` query

```
SELECT c FROM Incident c, TagIncident t
WHERE c.incidentID = t.incidentID
AND t.tagName = ?1
AND t.tagName != ?2
```

Also if you enable hibernate logging then you'll be able to see the generated queries and see if they work in external `SQL` program.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Comment: This SQL will result in different result. =(
Its not equivalent, where do I set this Logging? in the Bean?

Comment: If you're using spring boot you can put this property into `application.properties` file.